# Framework7: Dynamically load Component page from Tab

Tags: tabs, components, html-framework-7

I just found Framework7 and it looks promising as a base for mobile apps.

From navigation tabs I can load a Component Page which has dynamic data. But this data is only set when the application is loaded.

**Wanted:**

Every time user clicks on tab, load data and render page.

**Question**:
How can I make a component page load every time?

I have made an example from *framework7-template-tabs*. Check console showing when *pageInit* is called.

**Live**:

http://f7-navigate-component-question.surge.sh/

**Code**:

https://github.com/gotling/framework7-tab-component-page-question

Comment: what language are youusing for backend development?

Comment: I am not running any separate backend, this is pure JavaScript to be built into a Cordova application.

Comment: Framework7 is single page application. New page will be injected to DOM through ajax and previous page will be hidden. on DOM you will have total 3 pages all time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer in the [Framework 7 forum](http://forum.framework7.io/t/load-component-page-from-tab-refresh-every-time/1877).

1. Listen to page show events:

   `$('#view-catalog').on('tab:show', ...`
2. Refresh the page:

   ```
   $('#view-catalog').on('tab:show', function () {
     catalogView.router.navigate(catalogView.router.currentRoute.url, {
       reloadCurrent: true,
       ignoreCache: true
     });
   });
   ```

If using Framework7 **2.0.6** or newer that could have been simplified with:

```
$('#view-catalog').on('tab:show', function () {
  viewCatalog.router.refreshPage();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want some action to happen every time a particular tab is clicked/loaded, you can use the **show** event of the tab, documented [here](https://framework7.io/docs/tabs.html#tabs-events).

For example, to alert something every time tab2 is loaded, you could do this

```
$$("#tab2" ).on( "show", function( event, ui ) {
    myApp.alert("Tab loaded!");
} );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The `show` event was half of the problem. I got the answer to the refresh part elsewhere, will post an answer here.